# How to speed up the slow duplicate check extraction loop between dictionary lists?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I created the following to retrieve dictionaries that have duplicated specific keys between dictionary lists.
If there are 50,000 `l2` and so on, the loop of its parent will take a very long time.

`for d2 in l2` by itself doesn't take that long.
Since `for l in list` has about 300,000 data items, it takes about 50 minutes after the dust settles.

What are some ways to improve these?

```py
l = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tom"
  }
]

l2 = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "male",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male"
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sofía",
    "gender": "female"
    "country": "Mexico"
  },
]
```

Results sought

```py
[
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male"
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sofía",
    "gender": "female"
    "country": "Mexico"
  },
]
```

```py
new_datas = []
for l in list: # 300k data.
    l2 = [...] # 50k data.
    s = {d["name"] for d in l}

    new_datas.append([
        d2
        for d2 in l2
        if d2["name"] in s
    ])
```

Comment: A good [mcve] will show sample input, and expected output based on that input

Comment: Do you save new_data outside of the loop?
Because currently, you would overwrite new_data with every step in the outer for-loop.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I added the details I wanted to.

Comment: Generally I would trust the hashing to do a good job of implementing the `in` test, but in this case it might be worth sorting the names and then searching with `bisect`

Comment: > John Coleman To extract the same `name` value between two dictionary lists.

Comment: >Joffan Can you show us an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
l = [dic["name"] for dic in l]
cleanList = [dic for dic in l2 if dic["name"] not in l]
```

Alternatively, you could split the second list, and approach this problem with parallel computing.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by creating a `l_lookup` (I recommend you use a more expressive name though) via `set()`. At that point finding out if a name is in the set should be relatively fast.

```py
l = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Tom"}
]

l2 = [
    {"name": "John", "gender": "male", "country": "USA"},
    {"name": "Alex", "gender": "male", "country": "Canada"},
    {"name": "Sofía", "gender": "female", "country": "Mexico"},
]

l_lookup = set(x["name"] for x in l)
resutls = [item for item in l2 if item["name"] not in l_lookup]

print(resutls)
```

Should give you:

```
[
    {'name': 'Alex', 'gender': 'male', 'country': 'Canada'},
    {'name': 'Sofía', 'gender': 'female', 'country': 'Mexico'}
]
```